# Apache Delta Spike - QueryInvocationContext

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, cdi, java-ee-7, deltaspike

I think I might be having a problem with Apache Delta Spike.  I have a parent entity which is already persisted and I am adding a new child to it.  If I use the EntityRepository, I get a duplicate key problem on insert because it must think the parent is not yet persisted:

[code]
entityRepository.save(parent); // this throws a duplicate key exception

entityManager.merge(parent); // this works
[/code]

The funny thing is, is that I checked the source for CdiQueryInvocationContext, and it is doing the same exact thing I am doing, it checks if the parent has an identifier.  If so, it calls merge instead of persist.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'user-1' for key 'User_Environment'

Any ideas?  For the time-being, I'll use entityManager, but that defeats the purpose.

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: We recently had a discussion around transaction management.  If I had to guess, you're somehow calling it outside the normal transaction.  When this happens, it's trying to do a persist, hence why it's working.  Are you enabling transactions somehow?

Comment: Hi John, actually, the correct action is to do a merge not a persist.  If I manually invoke entityManager.merge(parent), it works.  I am invoking this from within a Java EE batch job so I believe that means it is controlling the transactions until the step completes?  Even using the @TransactionAttribute doesn't seem to help ...

Comment: I'd recommend posting to the DeltaSpike user mail alias, will likely get some internal traction.  When I mentioned persist I wasn't referring to the method, sorry.

Comment: Ok, will do.  Ah, just wanted to be sure as often times the most difficult problems are really simple ... if you know where to look.